# What is the average margin on a vehicle from a used car dealer?

Tags: car, negotiation, used-goods

I'm going to be looking for a used car here from a dealer, and I'd like to be as informed as possible when entering negotiations. A dealer has the car I want, used (looks like it was brought back from a lease), and I'm wondering how to estimate what they have invested in it. Is there a guideline for this, or any insight that can be offered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no rule of thumb -- people get ripped all of the time on trade-ins or when they sell cars to the dealer.

I think with used car negotiations, demand for the car is more important than their cost. If you're talking a 2007 Kia, there will be lots of room. If it's a 2009 Honda, they won't even discuss price.

In terms of negotiations, you'll only get the best price if you're willing to walk away at most dealers. I usually pick 2-3 candidate cars at different lots and show up on the last day of the month. If it's busy, look at the wall and find the #1 salesman and be a pain in the butt. Refuse to listen to the 4-square speil and walk away slowly if he doesn't negotiate. When I was in high school, my dad almost ran over a car salesman who literally jumped out in front of the car as we were leaving. My dad got his price and signed the contract right in the car.

Comment: I hate the four square. Last one I saw I turned upside down and said "If I see that again, I'm leaving." Thanks for the advice - I just have no idea how low to go on the cars I'm looking at.

Comment: Look around on the net, private sales, dealing listings etc. Figure out what the price range is and go from there. Don't be intimidated -- have fun!

Comment: I love the four square.  It lets me quickly communicate how I want to negotiate.  Step 1: I put a giant X through monthly payment and say I'm not going to discuss monthly payment.  Step 2: I put a giant X through interest rate - Either pay cash or pre-arrange financing elsewhere.  Step 3: I usually don't trade in cars, but sell them privately so I put a giant X through trade-in.  That leaves 1 square for total price.

Comment: @ Alex B. You didn't mention writing your own terms on it. I enjoy writing all over it and underlining what I've written multiple times as I talk. Even better, stabbing my finger at it and saying, "It says it right there."

Comment: @AlexB - totally awesome

Answer (score 5):

The low end lots generally buy at auction and add $1000 to their cost. Volume is their key. Except for bait cars, the really nice one to get you into the dealership, the longer a car sits the better your options to deal. Trouble is, if the car sits for weeks it probably has something wrong with it. My advice, as a former lower-end dealer, is set your price and buy the best you can afford. If a dealer is a few hundred dollars over, just let him know. If they want to move the car they will meet your price. If not, walk away.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly talking about new car purchases, but I think many of the points addressed in [this extremely good previous answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/615/what-are-some-tips-for-getting-the-upper-hand-in-car-price-negotiations/616#616) may help. The true gem is an article linked in one of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is no fixed margin – it all will depend upon the condition of car, the model, make, year and all.

Comment: I had a candid talk with a dealer for a car I bought that was immediately totalled.  He was interested in what I got from insurance and I was curious as to what he paid.  

So it was a hail damaged car he got at insurance auction for $2500.  I believe the insurance auction gets a lower price than the usual retail.  I paid him $5500 so pretty good deal for me I felt.  After I got hit by another driver literally on the way home from buying it, the insurance company paid me $8500.  So it really comes down to what customers are willing to pay and what they can get them for.